# Do these linear vs nonlinear buckling plots make sense?

Tags: finite-element-method, buckling

I am doing linear buckling analyses (where everything is linear), and nonlinear buckling analyses where you have nonlinear geometry enabled and nonlinear material behavior (hyperelastic material). Everything is done in COMSOL. The structure is fixed on one side, and a forced displacement of -0.01m in the x-direction on the opposite side. It seems the linear model buckles earlier compared to the nonlinear? What could be the reason for this, and does it look okay otherwise?

The blue lines are the nonlinear plots, and red/yellow dotted line endpoint is the buckling strain and stress - I have just made it into a line for easier visualization.

[image][image][image]

Comment: I suggest providing a table to list the resulting stresses and strains for ease of comparison.

Comment: If the geometry and loading are both "perfect" in the model there might be no reason for the nonlinear analysis to produce buckling. Your description seems to mean you are applying the load by controlling the *displacements* not the loads, in which case the nonlinear algorithm might by capable of tracking along an unstable branch of the structural response.  Try running the nonlinear analysis with a small amount of transverse load (e.g. 1% or 0.1% of the axial load) and see if you get a different result.

Comment: @alephzero - you are right in that I control the displacement and not a load, I dont apply any loads at all actually, just the displacement, this isnt wrong is it since it still seems to buckle? Because I know buckling analyses requires some sort of perturbation to see which way the model will buckle, do we get this perturbation when we apply displacement to this model? Should I apply 1N in the transverse direction and see if I get the same stress/strain curve?

Comment: @r13 - the linear buckling stress and strain is just a point so its easy to provide in a table, but what about the nonlinear curve, its a bunch of points and im not sure at which part of the curve would be appropriate to say it has buckled?

Comment: Your program shall indicate the buckling stress and the corresponding strain, doesn't it?

Comment: I think for the non-linear analysis, the blue line is the stress-strain curve in the plastic range. A point above the curve indicates the buckling stress is higher than the stress on the curve with the same strain reading.

Comment: The program gives buckling stress and corresponding strain for linear buckling, but nonlinear buckling is given by stress-strain data which is the blue curve you see. So linear buckling is really just a stress and strain point, but nonlinear is an entire curve, and I am not sure where on the curve one would say it has buckled. Should I for example say it is where the red arrow points?  https://imgur.com/a/fI5vw7y

Comment: What are the red dotted line and its end dot represent?

Comment: Before you are getting comfortable with the program. I suggest performing studies on a simpler structure - a rectangular cantilever, with a constant cross-section length a = 10 mm, and thickness b varies from 0.5 mm to 4 mm. Then apply a compressive load equal to (pi^2)*E*I/L^2 for each case and see what happens. Note E & L are constant for all cases.

Comment: The dot is the linear buckling stress and strain, the red line was just for visualization so it looks like a plot.

Comment: For imperfection, you can apply the force at an offset to the centerline of the width (say 
0.1*b +/- b/2). You can also try applying a constant force, which is to be derived using the thickest cross-section, to all cases.

Comment: But do I need to have imperfections? What I am trying to do is defined in this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.01359.pdf) as "Alternatively, one can perform geometric nonlinear analysis on a perfect structure with repeated buckling analysis, to more accurately predict the buckling strength in the deformed state. Here, we use the total Lagrangian approach for the description of geometric nonlinearity". Then the study says it does post-buckling analysis, which is the same study but with imperfections included.

Comment: r13 has the right idea. When you are trying to learn a new method always start with a problem where you *already know the answer*. Start with the simplest possible textbook problem and then work your way up in complexity.

Comment: Guys believe it or not im now new to this, I have done a bunch of buckling problems before. Although I guess im not the fastest learner in the world.